# Can't plot image with matplotlib after PIL convert('L')

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-imaging-library, spyder

I tried to convert RGB image into gray image and plot them. But I can't plot the gray image after PIL convert('L'). the following error was reported in the Spyder console (Python3.6). However, the original image can be plotted if i don't use the convert('L').

File "d:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 430, in _make_image
    if A.mask.shape == A.shape:

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'mask'

see my python code in below:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
file_name='images\\2.4.1.png'
im0 = Image.open(file_name)

plt.imshow(im0)
plt.show()

im = im0.convert('L')
plt.imshow(im, cmap='gray')
plt.show()  # Not working here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying using `LA` instead of just `L` as follows:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

file_name = r'images\2.4.1.png'
im0 = Image.open(file_name).convert('LA')
plt.imshow(im0, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

The parameter specifies the conversion mode, in your case the PNG file probably has an alpha channel, so the `A` is needed.

See also: [Pillow modes](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/handbook/concepts.html#modes)

Comment: thanks Martin! the converted image can be plotted now when i use the LA mode. but there is still an error reported.  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'tuple'

Comment: this error is a new error (which was not reported when i used mode L).  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'tuple' for the following code：tv = list(im.getdata()) #get pixel values
    tva = [ (255-x)*1.0/255.0 for x in tv]

Comment: You probably now have two values per pixel, the greyscale value and it's transparency, you would probably need to remove the transparency first.

Comment: Perhaps try `im0.split()[0]`

Comment: thanks! i just used a manual way removing the alpha channel and it works.  (btw, i checked the original image mode as RGB, why alpha channel is inside?)    tv = list(im.getdata()) #get pixel values
    print(len(tv))
    print(tv[234][0])
    for j in range (0, len(tv)):
        tv[j] = tv[j][0]
    print (tv)

    tva = [ (255-x)*1.0/255.0 for x in tv] 
    print(tva)

Comment: Not sure, png can have alpha channel, it is not mandatory though. Don't forgot to click on the grey tick under the up/down button to accept the answer as the accepted solution when finished.